# How to parse nested Objects in android to readable html

Tags: android, arrays, json, wordpress, arraylist

I have this code from `JSONParser.java`

```
 try{
            JSONArray postArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
            // Go through each post
            for (int i = 0; i < postArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject postObject = postArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Post post = new Post();
post.setCfs(postObject.getJSONObject("custom_fields").optString("entity", "N/A"));
```

that displays this

```
["Some text"]
```

I want it to display without `["` and `"]`

My Json for that specific part is as below

```
"posts":[{
"date":"2016-02-10 10:28:42",
"categories":[{}],
"tags":[],
"author":{"name":"admin"},
"custom_fields":{
                 "ref_number":["ITB NUMBER: ITB\/002\/2016"],
                 "deadline":["26 February, 2016"],
                 "entity":["Refugees (xxx)"]
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that "entity" is array and you should try something like that:

```
post.setCfs(postObject.getJSONObject("custom_fields").optJSONArray("entity").getString(0));
```

Comment: Thx. The code works like a charm, however i have edited and i want to pass the custom fields to the Webview.